# Mock Response.headers.get()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs

I have a method which extracts the fileName from a http response header:

```js
export const getFilenameFromResponse = response => {
 const filenameRegex = /filename[^=\n]*=["](.*?)["]/;
 const matches = filenameRegex.exec(
   response.headers.get('Content-Disposition')
 );
 return matches != null && matches[1] ? matches[1] : '';
};
```

Now I was going to write a unit test with Jest. Unfortunately, In cannot do something like

```
const headers = myHeaders = new Headers([
    ['Content-Disposition', 'form-data; fileName="testfile.txt"']
]);
const response = new Response ({headers: newHeaders});
result = getFilenameFromResponse(response)
expect(result).ToEqual('testfile.txt';
```

because the test fails because the result ist an empty string. I guess, it is due to wrong init of the response object.

Is there a way to mock `response.headers.get()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `spyOn` to set the behaviour of the `get` function:

```
const response = new Response ({headers: newHeaders});
const get = jest.spyOn(response.headers, 'get')
get.mockImplementation(()=> '')// do what ever `get` should to
```

The other way would be not create a real `Response` but just pass in a plain object:

```
const response = {
  headers: {
    get: jest.fn(()=> '')// do what ever `get` should to )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up here while searching for a solution for the same problem, but for Angular 2+.
The answer pointed me in the right direction:

```
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'content-disposition': ' filename=email.eml' });
  const body = new Blob(['a', 'b', 'c']);

  const response: HttpResponse<Blob> = new HttpResponse<Blob>({
    body,
    headers,
  });
```